# Initialization of AVAudioRecorder with aac

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I want to initialize a AVAudioRecorder with a aac file format, but it doesnt work...

Whats wrong with the following code?

```
soundFilePath = [soundFilePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"aac"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath isDirectory:FALSE];
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 'aac '] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];                                     //General Audio Format Settings 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];                                 //          "
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];                                  //          "
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 32] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];                                //Linear PCM Format Settings 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];                             //          "
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];                                 //          "
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityLow] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];                //Encoder Settings 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:96] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];                                    //          "
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey];                               //          "
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityLow] forKey:AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey];    //Sample Rate Conversion Settings

_recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:nil];
```

this allocation just returns nil...

Any help will be appreciated...!

Answer (score 3):

Remove every line about PCM, and change line with `formatIDKey` to

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
```

Btw, it's more proper to use `m4a` as an extension, rather than `aac`, because aac extension was used for MPEG2 AAC format.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 allows you to record to AAC.  Try this using "kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC" for the AVFormatIDKey.

Answer (score 0):

There are no settings to record to AAC, although you can convert on the fly:

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPAACAudioConverter

Comment: that API has glitch on the interruption!

Answer (score -1):

`[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_HE_V2] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];`
The format for this is an enumeration. Try to look into the enumerations. There is no formatIDKey for 'aac' . It has aacp and others.

Answer (score -1):

Just use following setting to record vocal in aac file.

```
    recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleLossless] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```